# NewsApi is not showing Error message (Android)(Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I am having trouble getting the `Error messages` when something goes wrong with the `Response` from the `NewsApi`. Everything works fine except for that. For example when the maximum amount of request is made for my `API KEY` no error message will show up except for the text I wrote.

Anybody experienced this before? I tried to use `Response.errorBody()` instead of `Response.message()` in the `ViewModel` however what came out was unintelligible jargon.

```
 //Api Get Request

interface NewsApi {
@GET("/v2/top-headlines")
suspend fun getNews(@Query("country") country : String, @Query("category") category : String?,@Query("page") pageNumber: Int = 1, @Query("apiKey") key : String = api_key) : Response<NewsResponse>
}


//Creating Retrofit instance and HTTP-logging-interceptors
object RetrofitHelper {
    private const val BASE_URL = "https://newsapi.org/v2/"
    private fun httpclient():OkHttpClient{
        val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()

    builder.addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
        setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)


        builder.addInterceptor(
            ChuckerInterceptor.Builder(application_class.context)
                .collector(ChuckerCollector(application_class.context))
                .maxContentLength(250000L)
                .redactHeaders(emptySet())
                .alwaysReadResponseBody(false)
                .build()
        )
    })
    return builder.build()
}

fun getInstance(): Retrofit {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .client(httpclient())
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
}
}

//Singleton to call the API
object NewsApiCall {
    val api by lazy {
        RetrofitHelper.getInstance().create(NewsApi::class.java)
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
class NewsRepository(val db:ArticleDatabase ) {
    suspend fun getBreakingNews(countryCode: String, category:String) =
    NewsApiCall.api.getNews(countryCode, category)
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class viewModel(var newsRepository:NewsRepository):ViewModel() {
    val breakingNews: MutableLiveData<Resource<NewsResponse>> = MutableLiveData()
    var breakingNewsResponse: NewsResponse? = null


    fun getBreakingNews(countryCode: String,category:String) = viewModelScope.launch {
    breakingNews.postValue(Resource.Loading())
    val response = newsRepository.getBreakingNews(countryCode, category)
    breakingNews.postValue(handleBreakingNewsResponse(response))
}

private fun handleBreakingNewsResponse(response: Response<NewsResponse>): Resource<NewsResponse> {
    if (response.isSuccessful) {
        response.body()?.let { resultResponse ->
            if (breakingNewsResponse == null) {
                breakingNewsResponse = resultResponse
            }
            else {
                val olArticles = breakingNewsResponse?.articles
                val newArticles = resultResponse.articles
                olArticles?.addAll(newArticles)
            }
            return Resource.Success(breakingNewsResponse ?: resultResponse)
        }
    }

    return Resource.Error(response.errorBody().toString())
}
}
```

**MainActivity**
,Calling the APIs from the MainActivity

```
    ViewModel.getBreakingNews("us", GENERAL)
```

**BreakingNewsFragment**, Displaying of the UI

```
    fun LoadingData_forRecyclerView(){
    viewModel.breakingNews.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { response ->
        when (response) {
            is Resource.Success -> {
                response.data?.let { newsResponse ->
                    RefreshData = newsResponse

                    Newsadapters.differ.submitList(newsResponse.articles.toList())
                    ProgressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    LoadingTextView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    ErrorImage.visibility = View.GONE
                }
            }
            is Resource.Error -> {
                response.message?.let { message ->
                    Log.e("Error", "An error accrued: $message")
                    ProgressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    LoadingTextView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    LoadingTextView.setText("The following error has occured $message!")

                }

            }
            is Resource.Loading -> {

                Log.e("Loading", "Loading")
                ProgressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                LoadingTextView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                ErrorImage.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }
    })
}
```

**Resource**, The utility resource class

```
    sealed class Resource<T>(
    val data: T? = null,
    val message: String? = null
) {
    class Success<T>(data: T) : Resource<T>(data)
    class Error<T>(message: String, data: T? = null) : Resource<T>(data, message)
    class Loading<T> : Resource<T>()
}
```

Comment: Can you please show what unintelligible jargon you are getting ?

Comment: I am currently unable to replicate the problem, however, I have a feeling that it happens due to, too many requests at once.